# Going back to the start of the code in Python (looping)

Tags: python

I'm new to programing in general. I have written a small program that converts numbers. My issue is how do I make the app go back to the begging for another convert after the first one is done? Thanks in advance.

```
price = None

while price is None:
    try:
        price = float(input('USD: '))
    except ValueError:
        print ("You are suppose to enter a number. ")
        

rate = float(0.385)
res = price * rate

con = res * 2.36 / 100

fres = con + res

print("HM: " + str(fres))
```

Comment: Wrap all your code inside another loop.

Comment: Python is a structured programming language - don't think of things in terms of *where in the code you go to*, instead, learn to use *looping and branching* constructs. If you want something to repeat - put it in some sort of loop

Comment: Also, you don't need to cast a literal float as the `float` type -- `0.385` is already a `float`.

Answer (score 1):

For educational purposes, I've drafted the following answer, and will explain the concepts:

#### Example code:

```
def convert(usd: float) -> float:
    """Convert USD to HM."""
    rate = 0.385
    return usd * rate * 0.0236 + (usd * rate)

while True:
    resp = input('USD to convert or (q to exit): ')
    if resp.lower() == 'q':
        break
    print(convert(float(resp)))
```

#### Concepts:

- The `convert` function takes as its input a float value to be converted from USD to HM, given the rate and (presumed) commission, and `return`s the calculated value.
- Next, a `while` loop is used to continuously prompt the user for a value to be converted. If the user types `'q'` to quit, the `if` statement validates to `True`, triggering the `break` statement, thus exiting the loop and exiting the program. Otherwise the `convert` function is called again.

#### Caveats:

- There is *no error handling* implemented in this case. This is intentional for your future experimenting and consideration.
- For example, if a value of `'a'` is provided to the input, the program will fall over and die.
- Please research and play with this code in efforts to 1) take it apart, 2) learn the concepts and 3) implement your own improvements.

Comment: Nice answer. But maybe static typing is not easy for a begginner to understand.

Comment: @TKirishima - Do you mean the type-hinting?

Comment: Yes. This is just a differnt name

Comment: Thank you very much. I will continue to experiment using the code.

Answer (score 0):

It is very simple to do what you are asking.
All you need to do add `while True:` to the top of your file, and indent the rest of it.

This makes it so that once your program is done doing its instructions, it checks if the condition we set (that condition being True) is True, which, because the condition itself is just `True`, will always be correct, which means it will always repeat itself.
The full piece of code with this implemented would be:

```
while True:

  price = None
  
  while price is None:
      try:
          price = float(input('USD: '))
      except ValueError:
          print ("You are suppose to enter a number. ")
          
  
  rate = float(0.385)
  res = price * rate
  
  con = res * 2.36 / 100
  
  fres = con + res
  
  print("HM: " + str(fres))
```

Hope this helped!

Comment: This is an infinite loop.

Comment: @S3DEV Is that not what you're asking for? It goes back to the beginning once the app is done, and that's all the info you gave in your post.

Answer (score 0):

In the interest of breaking things into smaller pieces, you would be well-advised to create a function to read a float that does so until it gets a valid input.

```
def stubborn_read_float(prompt, err):
  while True:    
    try:
      return float(input(prompt))
    except ValueError:
      print(err)
```

Now this:

> ```
> price = None
>
> while price is None:
>    try:
>        price = float(input('USD: '))
>    except ValueError:
>        print ("You are suppose to enter a number. ")
> ```

Can be written as:

```
price = stubborn_read_float('USD: ', 'You are suppose to enter a number.')
```

Which makes putting your logic into a loop easier:

```
while looping_condition:
  price = stubborn_read_float('USD: ', 'You are suppose to enter a number.')

  rate = float(0.385)
  res = price * rate

  con = res * 2.36 / 100

  fres = con + res

  print("HM: " + str(fres))
```